# allowing user to cancel foreground service

Tags: android, service, notifications

The code pasted below apparently (1) sets my service as a foreground service and (2) displays my icon on the tray at the top of the screen.  If the user taps my icon, today's date is quickly filickered - I suppose this is some kind of default behavior.  ContentTitle and ContentText never show (so what good are they?)

What I would like to have happen would be when the icon is tapped for a dropdown or popwindow of some kind to show allowing the user to make a choice to either cancel out or end my service.  I can't seem to find any examples of such functionality.  Can this be done?  How?

BTW, the sole purpose of my Notification is to make my service run in the foreground.  I never need to notify the user of anything.

Thanks, Gary

```
NotificationCompat.Builder b = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);

b.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
.setContentTitle("PhoneStalker")
.setContentText("Hello World");
```

Intent WhatIsThisIntentFor = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

```
b.setContentIntent(PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, WhatIsThisIntentFor, 0));
```

Notification n = b.build();

startForeground(5481, n);

Answer (score 0):

> Can this be done?

No. However, `setContentIntent()` could be a broadcast `PendingIntent` to a `BroadcastReceiver` that calls `stopService()` (or whatever your mechanism is to shut down your service).